# Add/Duplicate rows using Python / Pandas for specific Column value

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to insert new/duplicate rows into an excel using pandas data-frame when a particular column has a specific value. If the column value TRUE, duplicate that row and change its value too.

For ex:

```
Input

    A        B      C   D   
0   Red      111    A   2   
1   Blue     222    B   12  
2   Green    333    B   3
3   Black    111    A   2   
4   Yellow   222    D   12  
5   Pink     333    c   3
6   Purple   777    B   10
Output
    A        B      C   D   
0   Red      111    A   2   
1   Blue     222    Y   12  
2   Blue     222    Z   12
3   Green    333    Y   3
4   Green    333    Z   3
5   Black    111    A   2   
6   Yellow   222    D   12  
7   Pink     333    c   3
8   Purple   777    Y   10
9   Purple   666    Z   10
```

If you see here the in Column C, when I encounter specific Value = B, I want to duplicate that row only. change its value to Y and Z in original and duplicated rows respectively. (Do not duplicate if I encounter anything other than B.)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with replaced `C` column with replace filtered rows by `Z`, added `0.5` to index for alwasy correct `sort_index`:

```
df1 = df.replace({'C': {'B':'Y'}})
df2 = df[df['C'].eq('B')].assign(C = 'Z').rename(lambda x: x + .5)

df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
        A    B  C   D
0     Red  111  A   2
1    Blue  222  Y  12
2    Blue  222  Z  12
3   Green  333  Y   3
4   Green  333  Z   3
5   Black  111  A   2
6  Yellow  222  D  12
7    Pink  333  c   3
8  Purple  777  Y  10
9  Purple  777  Z  10
```

Or create 3 small DataFrames, without `B` values, filtered and set values and `concat` together:

```
mask = df['C'].eq('B')
df0 = df[~mask]
df1 = df[mask].assign(C = 'Y')
df2 = df[mask].assign(C = 'Z').rename(lambda x: x + .5)

df = pd.concat([df0, df1, df2]).sort_index().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach.

```
#Replace B with Y & Z first in column C
df.replace({'C': {'B': 'Y,Z'}}, inplace = True)

#Use "explode" Avaible on pandas 0.25 to split the value into 2 columns
df=df.assign(C=df.C.str.split(",")).explode('C')
```